# Android, 3.0+ spinner dialog style

Tags: android, styles, spinner, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to change the drawable used as background in the spinner dialog. Prior 3.0 it works fine, I just change the AlertDialog style to use my images, but that does not work when the activity is inheriting from a Holo theme. I am trying to find which style I have to override but I simply cannot find which one is responsible for this. 
I have tried inheriting from Theme.Holo.Dialog with no success.

Additionally, I am not able to completely override the selection selector drawable. Even when I supply my selector as background in the inherited @android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner, the device list selection is still visible under my selector.